# Calculate the Fourier series of $f(x)= \frac{1}{2} - |x-\frac{1}{2}| $

Tags: fourier-series

Calculate the Fourier series of $f(x)= \frac{1}{2} - |x-\frac{1}{2}|$

According to our definition of Fourier Series $\hat{f}(k) = \int_{0}^1 f(x) e^{-2 \pi ikx} dx $ is the k-th Fourier coefficient of $f$.

for $k\ne 0$
$$\int_{0}^1 ( \frac{1}{2} - |x -\frac{1}{2}|)e^{-2 \pi ikx} dx $$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^1 e^{-2 \pi ikx} dx + \int_{0}^1 |x -\frac{1}{2}|e^{-2 \pi ikx} dx$$

Integrating the first integral, it evaluates to zero $\left[ 
    \frac{1}{2} \frac{e^{-2 \pi ikx}}{-2 \pi ik} \right]_0^{1} = 0$
$$=0 + \int_{0}^1 |x -\frac{1}{2}|e^{-2 \pi ikx} dx$$
Now I substitute $t=x-\frac{1}{2}$ and change the integration boundaries to $t=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $t=\frac{1}{2}$
$$\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{1}{2}   |t|e^{-2 \pi ki(t+\frac{1}{2})} dt $$
I can pull out $e^{-\pi ik}$ because it does not depend on t and this $e^{-\pi ik}= (-1)^k $ according to my notes(correct me if I am wrong)
$$(-1)^k \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{1}{2}   |t|e^{-2 \pi ki(t)} dt$$
Now I use integration by parts and set $f=|t|$, $f^\prime(t)= \frac{t}{|t|}$, $g=\frac{e^{-2 \pi ikt}}{-2 \pi ik}$ and $g^\prime(t) = e^{-2 \pi ikt}$
$$(-1)^k \left[ 
    |t| \frac{e^{-2 \pi ikt}}{-2 \pi ik} \right]_\frac{-1}{2}^\frac{1}{2} - 
\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{1}{2}   \frac{t}{|t|} \frac{e^{-2 \pi ikt}}{-2 \pi ik} dt$$
The first integrand evaluates to zero. Thus we have
$$(-1)^k - 
\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{1}{2}   \frac{t}{|t|} \frac{e^{-2 \pi ikt}}{-2 \pi ik} dt$$
Then I use subsitution $u=\frac{t}{|t|}e^{-2 \pi ikt}$ and $\frac{du}{dt}= \frac{-2 \pi ikte^{-2 \pi ikt}}{|t|}$ and $dt=|t|\frac{e^{-2 \pi ikt}}{-2 \pi ik} du$
$$(-1)^k \left[ 
    t \frac{e^{-2 \pi ikt}}{-2 \pi ik} \right]_\frac{-1}{2}^\frac{1}{2}$$
$$=(-1)^k [\frac{1}{-4\pi ik} + \frac{1}{-4\pi ik}] = \frac{2}{-4\pi ik} = \frac{1}{-2\pi ik}= \frac{(-1)^k}{-2\pi ik}$$

for $k=0$ we know the $e^{-2 \pi ikx}=0$
$$\int_{0}^1 |x-\frac{1}{2}|dx = \frac{1}{4}$$

So $$Sf(x)= \frac{1}{4} +\sum_{k\ne 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{-2\pi ik}e^{2\pi ikx}= 
\frac{1}{4} -\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{k\ne 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k}e^{2\pi ikx}= \frac{1}{4} -\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{k\ne 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k}i\sin(2\pi kx)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{4} -\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k\ne 0} \frac{(-1)^k}{k}\sin(2\pi kx)$$

Could someone please verify if what I have done is correct. I hope this is clear enough as I had to let out some "somehow more obvious" parts otherwise I would have been very long. Also sorry if I had some typos.
Any help is appreciated and Thanks.

Comment: When you state the problem you should say on what interval.  Of course your result is a periodic function, so it is not equal to your $f(x)$ outside that interval.  The statement of the problem might be: "Computer the Fourier sine series of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$".  Of course there is also a cosine series for it, which will be different...

Comment: @GEdgar In our exercise course we have not specified the interval for this exercise but we integrate on [0,1] as it was set by our instructor. Is this what you mean?

Comment: What is the question here? Solution verification?

Comment: @LouisPan Yes, Please!

Comment: Also note this.  $f(0) = 0$, but $Sf(0) = 1/4$.  Does that mean there is an error in the calculation?

Comment: @GEdgar You are right I oversaw that the absolute value evalutes to zero with constant. Thanks for catching it!

Comment: @DougM So I have to do case distinction for $k=0$ and $k\ne 0$

Comment: I missed that you consider $k=0$ near the end.

Comment: Note $\sin(2\pi k x) = \sin(2\pi(-k)x)$, so you should combine the negative $k$ terms with the positive ones.

Comment: If we consider the periodic function that the fourrier series will generate... that is $f(x+1) = f(x)$ we should be generating an even function.  That would suggest that we have cosine terms and not sine terms in the series.

Comment: @GEdgar I have to consider the negative and positive $k$, which would result in more terms right?

Comment: @DougM I really have a hard time how to come up if it has cosine or sine term. Here I decided based on $-2\pi ik$ as stupid as it may sound.